# Setup HTTP timeouts in Spring 4 using java configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have implemented a shiny RESTful API server with Spring Boot, and I was asked to change the HTTP timeout parameters for the embedded HTTP server (Tomcat).

My question is: how to do that ?

Ideally, the solution would involve creating some configuration bean that set some magic Spring parameters.

To my understanding, I would need to setup what is explained in this link http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-timeout, but for my whole server.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

**To avoid misunderstandings**

- I have found links that explain how to do so for HTTP requests sent by my server, such as http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/27/how-to-set-http-request-timeouts-with-spring-resttemplate/. This is however not what I want: I want to configure the HTTP timeouts for the requests to my server.
- I have found links that explain how to set the session timeout (I use spring session). This is however not what I want: I am at the HTTP protocol level, this has nothing to do with sessions.

Comment: "HTTP timeout parameters" is a bit vague. There are a number of timeout options available on Tomcat's connectors, but they may not give you the desired behaviour. For example, you may actually need to configure the timeout on the client side. What behaviour are the people who asked you to "change the HTTP timeout parameters" actually looking for?

Comment: Thank you for caring. When the server sends some data, I am looking for some maximum time the server waits for the client to receive it. I guess this is in case the client requests for some data, and never retrieves it.

Comment: The server doesn't know if the client's received the data, just that it's sent it. Only the client can control how long it'll wait to receive the data. You can configure a server-side timeout for the delay between the connection from the client being established and the client actually making a request. I think that might be as close as you can get.

Comment: OK, let me confirm with the manager that asked me to do that, he was pretty confused too.